# sql server como asignar una primary key a una tabla que contiene datos

Tags: sql-server-2012

tengo una tabla que es o se llama Facturas  la cual al momento de crearse se creo sin una PK esta tabla ya tiene varios registros y ahora deseo agregarle una columna mas con una PK ya que los registros que necesito de esta tabla factura quiero que sea un registro único.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de agregar la Pk necesitas agregar el campo **"id"** que quieres utilizar en tu caso no se puedes llamarlo **facturaId** y con la instrucción IDENTITY lograremos que el campo sea auto incremental, de la siguiente manera:

```
 alter table Facturas add IdFacturas int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1);
```

Después  tienes que agregar la PK

```
 alter table Facturas add primary key (IdFacturas);
```

**Buscar en google lo siguiente** [alter table primary key](https://www.google.cl/search?ei=28VXWruANsawwASrspTQDw&q=alter%20table%20primary%20key%20sql%20server&oq=alter%20table%20primary%20key%20sql%20server&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i71k1l4.0.0.0.468177.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ZpCa_QzEgME) **sql server**

y voilà [add-primary-key-to-existing-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794659/add-primary-key-to-existing-table)

PD: deberías poner tu tabla como información adicional para que los demás te entiendan, en este caso es mas fácil ya que lo que necesitas es algo conocido.

Comment: Muchas gracias. funciono sin problemas